# How to use replaceAll() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

*I have string and there are alot of character which is "\" so I want to remove all of them but when I use*

```
string.replace("\\","");
```

*it removes just first character. There is no replaceAll in reactnative. How can I do that ?*

Comment: Has nothing to do with 'react-native' specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **use a regex with the `g` modifier** whichs means `globally`, that will apply the regex as many times as necessary. You can use a [tool like this](https://regex101.com/) to build and test your regex.

```js
console.log('hello\\world\\'.replace(/\\/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use regex in your `replace`.

Example:

```js
const string = "aaabbbcccaaa";

// Removes first "a" only
console.log(string.replace("a", ""));

// Removes all "a"
console.log(string.replace(/a/g, ""));
```

Comment: This works of course but you don't need `[ ]` for the `a`